# Visual Studio Team Services: GULP build task failing on 'CANNOT FIND MODULE'

Tags: msbuild, npm, gulp, build-process, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a CI for my project team. I am pushing an angular/node project to a git repo in Team Services. The build triggers fine until it hits the gulp task. Before that gulp task run steps 1-3:

```
1. npm config set cache C:\Dev\nodejs\npm-cache --global
 2. npm install
 3. npm cache clean
 **4. gulp default** 
 5. deploy to azure
```

The reasons for steps 1 & 2 is because npm install was failing until i set the cache.

my error output:

```
2016-04-28T17:51:21.0694993Z [command]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd default --gulpfile C:\a\1\s\PolicyUI\PolicyUI\gulpfile.js --packagePath=C:\a\1\a
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1707118Z module.js:338
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1707118Z     throw err;
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1717126Z     ^
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1717126Z Error: Cannot find module 'merge-stream'
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1717126Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1727127Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1727127Z     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1738110Z     at require (module.js:384:17)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1747120Z     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\a\1\s\PolicyUI\PolicyUI\gulpfile.js:8:13)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1747120Z     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1757124Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1757124Z     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1767126Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2016-04-28T17:51:25.1767126Z     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

merge-stream IS there locally and works fine on my machine.

Does anyone know why this fails???

Whenever a build happens in team services, is that an isolated powershell environment where it is building??

Comment: What build agent are you using? Hosted Build Agent or your own build agent? Is "merge-stream" module installed before run gulp task?

Comment: hosted build agent. the first command in the build step IS 'npm install' and it doesn't even work every time (that's why i had to add the cache steps) @Eddie-MSFT

Comment: Can you share the error log when run npm install without cache set?

Comment: And in the "Advanced" settings for Gulp task, can you set the "Working Directory" to the folder where the your gulp file placed and then try the build again?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue in our team. We had to modify the powershell script manually to point to the right location of the gulp file. There were some path issues in the default script provided. Please look into it and you may find some answers.

Thank you.

Comment: in the default gulp build step, i changed the path to my gulp file and it worked. it is reaching my gulp file no problem. the problem i think is with the npm install